# Recipe for `final`: omit `virtual`?

Tags: c++, final, c++11

**Is it a valid recipe to say that if I write `final` (to a member function) one should not write `virtual`?**

In a base class, `final` methods would make no sense:

```
struct Driver {
    virtual void print();
};
```

If one would add `final` to `print()` this would defy the reason for polymorphism in the first place. So that would be useless (though possible).

When I derive from this class I can detect errors *with* `final`, but only *without* `virtual`:

```
struct KeyboardDriver : public Driver {
    virtual void prynt() final;    // Oops: typo, but compiler-ok
};

struct MouseDriver : public Driver {
    void prynt() final;    // Error: Hooray, compiler found my typo
};
```

The additional `final` for `KeyboardDriver::prynt` was legal. Because `final` only requires the member function to be `virtual` -- the compiler lets this pass (FDIS 9.2p9).

But when I leave out the `virtual` the typo makes this function non-virtual -- it overrides nothing, i.e. no virtual function. Therefore `final` without `virtual` serves the same purpose to this respect as `override` does.

Update: **Is my analysis correct? Does the functionality of `final` without `virtual` include that one of `override`?**

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Or are you just whittering?

Comment: It is a question, I will add it more clearly

Comment: "So that would be useless (though possible)." That's not necessarily useless; there are times when you need certain aspects of polymorphism without actually making it polymorphic. Sometimes, you have to make a type polymorphic just to allow certain kinds of casting and type derivation. I used a `private` empty `virtual` function, which I could make it `final` as a syntactic sign that it should not be used.

Comment: @Nicol: I see. Yes, of course. I did not think of that. Dynamic loading of a modules containing C++-classes? Hmm...

Comment: @towi Actually, I needed to be able to `dynamic_cast` (the horror!), and you can only do that on polymorphic types. But the `dynamic_cast` was in fact save, as I was using the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: CRTP... I think had fun with that using Spirit, the parsing lib, If I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. Not marking a `final` member as `virtual` avoids declaring a new, non-overriden member and catches mistakes. However, since that's the purpose of `override`, it may be simpler to just use `final override`; then whether the member is marked `virtual` or not won't matter at all.

Answer (score 3):

That is not what `final` is for.  What you are looking for is `override`.

```
struct Base { 
  virtual void print();
};

struct Derived : Base {
  void prynt() override; //compiler error
};

struct Good : Base {
  void print() override; //no compiler error
};
```

If you mark a function as `override` when it does not, then you get an error.  Combined with your final function, you get all the comforts of compiler checked safety, with the clarity of explicitly marking functions `virtual` when coding standards demand it.

```
struct Best : Base {
  virtual void print() final override;
};
```

Comment: I can't find in the grammar where `explicit` is allowed to appear right here. However `final` can as a *class-virt-specifier*, but that uses the semantics of `final` and not `override` quite obviously.

Comment: @Luc: Hmm... Its very possible I'm working off an old copy of the draft, let me do some more research.

Comment: Indeed, `explicit` and `new` were removed.

Comment: @Dennis: I know, that this is not the main intent of `final`. But as far as I can see semantically *final* implies *override* (why else finalizing something, if it is not overriding it). Therefore I argue that one can use `final` to include the meaning of `override` -- and that works if (and only if) does not use `final` together with `virtual`.

Comment: @towi: or, you can actually use override, which always works. Relying on `final` just replaces one possible mistake with another. Particularly since many coding standards require the use of `virtual` in derived classes already... I wouldn't expect a lot of exceptions just for functions marked `final`

Comment: @dennis: I agree. I think I arrived now at the policy that "final alone but _with_ virtual" is a bit dangerous, and either suggest -- like you said -- "if final then also override" or (for the typing-savers) "if final and not override, then also not virtual". As far as I can see this would be a valid rule for a "C++11-lint" program someone might write.

Comment: @towi That would be a _terrible_ rule. The rule is to use the keywords to mean what they mean and use them in the places where they have those meanings. If you intend to override a function, you use `override`. The lack of `override` means that you do not intend to override the base version. Similarly, if you intent to prevent someone from overriding something in a derived class, then you use `final`. The lack of `final` means that it's OK to override it. And by all rights, you should _always_ use `virtual` on any method that is virtual, even if you don't technically need it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is an error, it's just a virtual function that can not be overloaded. Same thing that would happen if the function were declared virtual in a parent class, since virtual declarations are inherited. It would make no sense to forbid it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my analysis correct? Does the functionality of final without virtual include that one of override?

No. The reason that this was a compiler error:

```
void prynt() final;    // Error: Hooray, compiler found my typo
```

Is because `final` is only allowed on *virtual* functions. The compiler is complaining because you used it on a function that isn't virtual.

There is nothing syntactically wrong about this line:

```
virtual void prynt() final;    // Oops: typo, but compiler-ok
```

It may not be what you want, but this is legitimate (and even meaningful, depending on the circumstances) code.

The problem you are encountering is due to wanting to do this:

```
struct Driver {
    virtual void print();
};
struct MouseDriver : public Driver {
    void print();
};
```

Omitting the `virtual` is technically legal. But personally, I've always felt that it was bad form. You're putting vital information (which functions are overridden) into another class. I think it was a mistake to even allow this to compile.

If you want to avoid this problem, then explicitly state `virtual` on *all* virtual functions, and use `override` in the places where you mean to create a new function. Then, this will fail to compile correctly.

```
struct Driver {
    virtual void print();
};
struct MouseDriver : public Driver {
    virtual void print() override;
};
```

Comment: I completely agree. "Once virtual, always virtual" should have been a necessity, yes. But a "compiler error"? I did not mean `virtual void prynt() final;` was complained by the compiler. Is passes through, and thats what I don't like. But I take your point: If `override` is what one want's, one should write `override`.